# XML validation for big files passes even with errors

Tags: xml, validation, visual-studio-code, w3c-validation

I'm struggling with my big xml file (28000 rows).
This xml sometimes has some duplicate closing tag

```
eg: <question>what can i do?</question>>
```

All the xml validator online doesn't find the error with big files like this and give me the pass on the code.

I tried the w3c xml validator and it also doesn't work [(link)](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp).

My xml is autogenerated by some really old legacy code and noone is going to fix the problem so i was looking for some validator online or software to do it for me without going in notepad looking for the tag.

Anyone has any idea on how should i handle this problem? Am I missing something? any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The extra '>' is actually valid xml and is treated as character data (see 
https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax), that's why it passes validation.

If you know the exact structure of the xml you can try to define a xml schema for it and validate with that, eg:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="question" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Will trigger a validation error for:

```
<root>
    <question>what can i do?</question>>
</root>
```